# Validate user signature in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a signature pad designed in my XAML with the help of custom renderers. I am getting the user's signature and saving the signature as an image successfully. However, even when the user has not signed on the signature, and when I am clicking the `Save` button, an image is saved.

My question is how can I validate the user's signature ? How can I check if the user's has signed or not ?

The renderers that I am using is the following : https://github.com/15mgm15/Xamarin-Forms-Signature

Please help.

Comment: When you say 'validate' you mean compare it with other previously registered?

Comment: Not.. validate I mean if the signature pad is blank.

Comment: I've used this one: [Xamarin.Forms SignaturePad](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad) . It have a lot of resources you certainly will need.

Comment: I have already used the one provided in the question though :/ 

Can I achieve to check if the signature pad is empty with the custom renderer that I have used?

Comment: As it is an image, the choices you have is proccess the image content or verify the amount of bytes of it.

Comment: that is a feature I definitely have to add!

Comment: @MarioGalván : I believe you are the creator of this renderer. Do you have an alternative of checking if the user has signed or not ?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza : I have tried to compare with its base64 encoded string. It works fine. But the issue arises when the check is performed on a different device. Please, can you advise how to cater for this?

Comment: @jones can you describe more the issue you're having in different devices?

Comment: I have encoded the blank image in base64. But when I make the check on different mobile phones, the check does not go through.

Comment: I think this deserves another question here on StackOverflow. Post it like a question and provide the information needed to let us help you =)

Comment: @jones at this time there is nothing, a easy way to check it is with a flag, and turn of this flag if the clear the pad.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handled it with mine:

.xaml

```
<controls:SignaturePadView x:Name="signaturePad" CaptionText="Sign Here"/ >
```

.cs

```
if (!signaturePad.IsBlank)
{
  // Save signature image
}
else
{
  await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please sign to confirm material check out.", "Ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Signature Pad for Xamarin and Windows](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad) component is checking whether the GetStrokes ().Count == 0 or not to ensure the signature pad is not blank. Please refer the same

[Github](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad)

Comment: But I am not using this component. I am using a custom renderer as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi jones, they are also implemented the same using the custom renderer as yours. You may need to create a bindable property in your ImageWithTouch class (say IsBlankProperty) and needs to be updated in the DrawView OnTouchEvent or by counting the strokes user has made

Comment: How to do this ?

Comment: Please give more details to help you.....Which architecture you are following ? MVVM ? How are you going to access the ImageWithTouch class property from your project ?

Comment: Having the same issue I don't know how to get that IsBlank property in renderer without imagewithtouch to recognise can anyone help me?